# Magento 2: Upgrade/Update using Command Line & Composer

Tags: magento, magento2

Upgrade/Update using Command Line & Composer magento2. How can I use command line and composer to upgrade my magento to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.1 --no-update
composer update

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Note: In Ubuntu/Debian Linux, if you are having permission issues then try using sudo at the beginning of every command. For example, sudo composer update

After you have upgraded Magento 2, you can check your Magento’s version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

If you get cache write permission error when you browse your Magento site after upgrade, then run the following command to give write permission to pub and var directories:
    chmod -R 777 pub var